# I'm confused by Model (call 'Model.connection' to establish a connection) message received in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, database-connection, ruby-on-rails-5

I'd noticed this recently after starting my first Rails 5 app, but up until this point, it wasn't causing an issue I couldn't overcome.

The point that I couldn't overcome came when I tried to write my first Rake task. I continued to get this error:

```
ruby 2.3.3-p222
╳  ad_board categories ◆◆ rake reprocess_images                                                                                                                  
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant Image
/home/myname/Documents/workspace/ad_board/lib/tasks/reprocess_images.rake:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@myapp/gems/rake-11.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@myapp/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@myapp/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => reprocess_images
```

I assumed I either wrote the rake task incorrectly(could still be the case) or that I had made my model `image.rb` in this case `images.rb`, but I had not.

When I went to `rails c` to see if I could figure out what was going on, after typing in `Image`, expecting to get back Image's parameters, I instead got back this error message:

```
[1] pry(main)> Image
=> Image (call 'Image.connection' to establish a connection)
```

So, I tried a few other things:

```
[2] pry(main)> Image.connected?
=> false
[3] pry(main)> User.connected?
=> false
[4] pry(main)> Gallery.connected?
=> false
```

and...

```
[1] pry(main)> Image
=> Image (call 'Image.connection' to establish a connection)
[2] pry(main)> User
=> User (call 'User.connection' to establish a connection)
[3] pry(main)> User.first
  User Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<User id: 1, email: "user@example.com", created_at: "2017-01-10 21:43:53", updated_at: "2017-01-10 21:43:53", name: "First User", role: "admin", auth_token: nil>
[4] pry(main)> Image.first
  Image Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "images".* FROM "images" ORDER BY "images"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Image:0x0000000595bf00 id: 1, file: "creativity.jpg", user_id: 20, created_at: Tue, 10 Jan 2017 21:43:58 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Tue, 10 Jan 2017 21:43:58 UTC +00:00>
```

I also typed in `Image.connection`, but all it did, like the above code, was to temporarily make a connection. As soon as I left the console I continued to get the original error message from running my rake task.

I went back into the console and typed `Image`, and received the message `=> Image (call 'Image.connection' to establish a connection)`

So, the first question, is why does the "connection" break, does not establish or stay on its own? I have not run into this before now, in my limited experience.

The obvious follow-up is, how do I fix the issue and maintain a connection?

Thanks in advance for any insight into this issue you can give me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The connection doesn't break, it just doesn't connect until you do something where it needs to.  There isn't anything to fix connection wise.  Your actual rake issue is that it can't find the `Image` model. I suspect this is because you're not telling rake to load the rails environment.

In rails you can do the following in rake

```
task reprocess_images: :environment do                              
  Image.find_each do |img|
    #do something
  end                                                                   
end
```

The `:environment` tells it to load the rails environment which will autoload things for you.

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
console { ActiveRecord::Base.connection }
```

in your development environment to ignore it.